# Cannot access any remote resource after connecting to Cisco VPN on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I have installed Cisco vpn client version 5.0.07.0290 on Vista Business SP2. I am able to successfully connnect to the vpn. But after connecting I am not able to access any resource in the vpn (like database, other computers in the network etc.). I have tried the following without any success :

1. Older versions of the client
2. Other vpn clients like Shrewsoft : same issue as the cisco vpn client
3. Disabled Internet Connection Sharing service
4. Installed the client in the root administrator account
5. Run the installer as administrator
6. Run the vpngui and ipsecdialer in XP compatibility mode and as administrator

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Can somebody please help me in troubleshooting this issue?

P.S : I've Zonealarm firewall, can that be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Any firewall, including the one included with Windows, can be an issue. So, first step is to disable all firewalls and antiviruses (temporary, of course).

Second step is to effectively log in as Administrator and try to connect. On Vista and 7, a user from group Administrators has less privileges than Administrator itself.

Third step is to verify your routing table. You can use the command "route print" to see all routes on your system and you can verify if communication to the IP addresses of the VPN are correctly routed over your VPN network device (should pe a tap or br device).